# How do I import a specific word from a .txt file into Python as a string variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to use a .txt file as a local database for around 4000 different words. They are organized in the following format:

```
wordOne
wordTwo
wordThree
wordFour
...
wordFourThousand
```

Each word has it's own separate line. My goal is to be able to import a specific word from this text file based on a random variable. I put an example of what I have so far below. Ignore my crummy camelCase habit.

```
import random
wordName=random.randint(1,4000)
with open('wordList.txt') as wordList:
    #use the variable wordName to open the word on that particular line number in the .txt file and set it as a variable named wordString
print(wordString)
```

So if the variable wordName is equal to 32, it will open up the word on line 32 of the text file and print it to the console. I hope this isn't too easy of a question, I am a bit new to Python and trying to get some practice moving data from one source to another. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: The simplest solution would be loading the entire file into emory as a list of lines

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
words = wordlist.readlines()
```

then can do:

```
words[wordName - 1]
```

to retrieve the word you want, also you won't have to reopen the text file if you save words as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Reading 4k words into memory is peanuts, so I'd not optimize anything here. The simplest approach is using [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random

with open('filename.txt') as fp:
    words = list(fp)

random_word = random.choice(words).strip()  # strip will remove the trailing \n
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do what you have described is using the read lines methods.

Assuming the below is your text file

words.txt:

```
one
two
three
...
```

You would do the following:

```
with open("words.txt") as textFile:
    words = textFile.readlines()
    print(words[1])
```

output

```
two
```

Remember the list index start from zero, so if you wanted `words[i]` where `i = 1` to return the first element you would do `words[i + 1]`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote you but I really do appreciate it!